# how to make a slideshow from ArrayList of ImageURLs by using ViewFlipper in android?

Tags: java, android, runnable, viewflipper, universal-image-loader

I have made a simple demo android app,In that I am getting some Images url from the API,And I am filling an arrayList with them.I want to made a slideshow of that imageurl from the server ,I have seen the view flipper example but not getting how to do it in my case.
**ViewFlipperAdapter.java**

```
package com.epe.smaniquines.adapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.epe.smaniquines.R;
import com.epe.smaniquines.adapter.CatalogAdapter.Viewholder;
import com.epe.smaniquines.util.Const;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;

public class FlipperAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<String> urls;
    private Context mContext;
    private DisplayImageOptions options;
    public static ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public FlipperAdapter(Context paramContext, ArrayList<String> urls) {
        this.urls = urls;
        this.mContext = paramContext;
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(paramContext));

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheOnDisc(true)
                .showStubImage(R.drawable.noimage)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.noimage).build();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return urls.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return urls.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int paramInt, View paramView, ViewGroup paramViewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater localLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
                .getSystemService("layout_inflater");
        Viewholder localViewholder = null;
        if (paramView == null) {
            paramView = localLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.raw_flip,
                    paramViewGroup, false);
            localViewholder = new Viewholder();

            localViewholder.proImg = ((ImageView) paramView
                    .findViewById(R.id.iv_flip));

            paramView.setTag(localViewholder);

        } else {
            localViewholder = new Viewholder();
            localViewholder = (Viewholder) paramView.getTag();
        }

        imageLoader.displayImage(urls.get(paramInt), localViewholder.proImg,
                options);

        return paramView;

    }

    static class Viewholder {
        ImageView proImg;

    }
}
```

**raw.flip**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_flip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**main.java**

```
package com.epe.smaniquines.ui;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Timer;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Images;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AdapterViewFlipper;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

import com.epe.smaniquines.R;
import com.epe.smaniquines.adapter.FlipperAdapter;
import com.epe.smaniquines.util.Const;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;

public class DetailsActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    ImageView proImage, ivSave, ivInfo, ivPlay, ivBak, iv_share;
    RelativeLayout rl_botm, rl_option;
    TextView tv_facebuk, tv_twiter, tv_nothanks, tv_email, tv_save;
    String big_img;
    ArrayList<String> resultArray;
    private DisplayImageOptions options;
    public static ImageLoader imageLoader;
    RelativeLayout rl_info;
    public boolean flag = false;
    int i = 0;
    private int PicPosition;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    int mFlipping = 0;
    ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
    Timer timer;
    int flagD = 0;
    String data;
    String shareType;
    File image;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
        initialize();
        /*
         * Intent i = getIntent(); data = i.getStringExtra("data"); shareType =
         * i.getStringExtra("type");
         */

        big_img = getIntent().getStringExtra(Const.TAG_BIG_IMG);
        resultArray = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("array");
        System.out.println("::::::::::::::ArraySize::::::::" + resultArray);
        imageLoader.displayImage(big_img, proImage, options);
        ivInfo.setOnClickListener(this);
        ivPlay.setOnClickListener(this);
        tv_email.setOnClickListener(this);
        tv_facebuk.setOnClickListener(this);
        tv_nothanks.setOnClickListener(this);
        tv_save.setOnClickListener(this);
        tv_twiter.setOnClickListener(this);
        iv_share.setOnClickListener(this);
        ivBak.setOnClickListener(this);
        // viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
        imageLoader.displayImage(big_img, proImage, options);
        proImage.postDelayed(swapImage, 3000);

    }

    public void open(View view) {
        /*
         * Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); screenshotUri
         * = Uri.parse(big_img); sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
         */
        /*
         * sharingIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
         * "Body text of the new status");
         * sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Traffic At");
         * sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
         * startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,
         * "Share image using"));
         */
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("*/*");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello test"); // <- String
        Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(image.getPath());
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image using"));
    }

    void initialize() {
        proImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_det);
        ivInfo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_info);
        ivPlay = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_play);
        ivBak = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_back);
        rl_botm = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_bottom);
        rl_option = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_options);
        tv_save = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_save);
        tv_email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
        tv_facebuk = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_facebook);
        tv_nothanks = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_no_thanks);
        tv_twiter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_twiter);
        rl_option.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        iv_share = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_share);
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration
                .createDefault(DetailsActivity.this));
        rl_info = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_info);
        rl_info.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        resultArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.iv_share:
            rl_option.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            break;

        case R.id.iv_play:
            proImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            AdapterViewFlipper flipper = (AdapterViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
            flipper.setAdapter(new FlipperAdapter(DetailsActivity.this,
                    resultArray));
            break;
        case R.id.iv_back:
            finish();
            break;
        case R.id.tv_email:
            rl_option.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                    new String[] { "youremail@yahoo.com" });
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message");
            email.setType("message/rfc822");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email,
                    "Choose an Email client :"));
            break;
        case R.id.tv_save:
            save();
            rl_option.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case R.id.tv_facebook:
            save();
            open(v);
            rl_option.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case R.id.tv_no_thanks:
            rl_option.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case R.id.tv_twiter:
            rl_option.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case R.id.iv_info:
            rl_option.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (flag) {
                rl_info.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                flag = false;
            } else {
                rl_info.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                flag = true;
            }

            break;

        }
    }

    // slide show..!!!

    MediaPlayer introSound, bellSound;
    Runnable swapImage = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            myslideshow();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };

    private void myslideshow() {
        PicPosition = resultArray.indexOf(big_img);
        if (PicPosition >= resultArray.size())
            PicPosition = resultArray.indexOf(big_img); // stop
        else
            resultArray.get(PicPosition);// move to the next gallery element.
    }

    //

    // SAVE TO SD CARD..!!
    void save() {
        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) proImage.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
        File sdCardDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        File dir = new File(sdCardDirectory.getAbsolutePath()
                + "/3sManiquines/");
        image = new File(sdCardDirectory, "3s_" + System.currentTimeMillis()
                + ".png");
        dir.mkdirs();
        boolean success = false;

        // Encode the file as a PNG image.
        FileOutputStream outStream;
        try {

            outStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
            /* 100 to keep full quality of the image */

            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();

            success = true;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (success) {
            addImageToGallery(dir + "", DetailsActivity.this);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image saved with success",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Error during image saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }//

    public static void addImageToGallery(final String filePath,
            final Context context) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
        values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, filePath);

        context.getContentResolver().insert(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                values);
    }

    // facebook...
    public void sharetext(String text) // Text to be shared
    {

        Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        share.setType("text/plain");
        share.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "TITLE");
        share.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share via"));
        finish();

    }

    public void shareimage(String text) // argument is image file name with
                                        // extention
    {

        Intent shareimage = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        shareimage.setType("*/*");// for all
        shareimage.setClassName("com.android.mms",
                "com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity");

        shareimage.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, resultArray.indexOf(big_img));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareimage, "Share Image"));
        finish();
    }

}
```

**main.xaml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_det_hdr"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_nav_bg" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_back" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titledetail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="CATALOG"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_main_det"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/rl_bottom"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rl_det_hdr"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_det"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        <AdapterViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/flipper"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_options"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/rl_bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/frame"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_twiter"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Twitter"
            android:textColor="#1D88FC"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/sep1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.75dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_twiter"
            android:background="#cecece" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_facebook"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sep1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Facebook"
            android:textColor="#1D88FC"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/sep2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.75dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_facebook"
            android:background="#cecece" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_email"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sep2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Email"
            android:textColor="#1D88FC"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/sep3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.75dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_email"
            android:background="#cecece" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_save"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sep3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Save"
            android:textColor="#1D88FC"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/sep4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.75dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_save"
            android:background="#cecece" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_no_thanks"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sep4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="No Thanks"
            android:textColor="#1D88FC"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/rl_bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/frame"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_twiter"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Info"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/sep1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.75dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_twiter"
            android:background="#cecece" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_facebook"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sep1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Ead one Eno"
            android:textColor="#1D88FC"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_bottom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_nav_bg"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_play"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/play_btn" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/about_us" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_share"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/share_icon" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AdapterViewFlipper would be the best way to go since, in a ViewFlipper you need to pre define the views.

Inside onCreate :

```
ArrayList<String> urls; 
//Fetch and set urls to this ArrayList; 

AdapterViewFlipper flipper = (AdapterViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
flipper.setAdapter(new FlipperAdapter(urls));
```

FlipperAdapter.java

For loading image from urls, I'd suggest the use of the Universal Image Loader library : https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

```
public class FlipperAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<String> urls;

    public FlipperAdapter(ArrayList<String> urls) {
        this.urls = urls;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return urls.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return urls.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.viewLayout, parent, false);
        }

        ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageLoader.displayImage(urls.get(position), image, null);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Edit 1 : viewLayout.xml (This will contain the layout of the items you want to display inside the adapterViewFlipper)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">   
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Shivam...But can you tell me what should be the "ViewLayout" Please brother..thank you in advance

Comment: Check Edit 1 for the layout.

Comment: Shivam Please see my edited code..It only gives me first image from the arrayLis..Please help

Comment: Doesn't change images on swiping ?

Comment: are you sure you have all the urls inside the ArrayList ?

Comment: yes....I have printed size of arrayLis for checking..may b i have inplemented in onclick event so that giver only one image?is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the problem but try initializing + setting the adapter of the viewFlipper inside your initialize() method.

Comment: sorry I am not getting...shivam

Comment: This should already work. I am not sure what the problem is. Maybe there's a problem in your main.xml where you've added the AdapterViewFlipper. Make sure that it's visible on the screen and there are no other views on top of it.

Comment: I have added main.xaml pls se..:(

Comment: Try adding android:autoStart="true" to the AdapterViewFlipper and see what happens when you click the iv_det image.